# How Christians are expected to accommodate or view the existence and presence of other religions vis a vis Christianity?

Tags: belief, religious-practice, religion

We as Christians acknowledge the God’s plan of salvation at work first through Judaism  in OT and then through Christianity in NT. So this question does not apply to Judaism.

This plan of salvation right from man’s fall in Genesis to the NT, is like a well oiled machine, where the OT and NT are in sync with each other. This I am saying because we accept OT in same spirit as NT and Judaism as from God because that is how God wanted to mould Jewish people to make them ready for receiving His promised Messiah.  Contrary to this we find all other religions not at all compatible with each other and that applies their relation with Judaism and Christianity also.

So what would be the best viewpoint to take on these other religions? How Christians are expected to accommodate or view them vis a vis our belief. Do we have to treat them as teaching that did not have origin from God but only from human thinking or from some hallucinations?

I am looking for answers from the Christian point of view only and not from any other position of belief/unbelief.

#### Are all other religions man-made?

Comment: Your question is very, very similar to this:  http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8385/in-light-of-grace-how-does-a-christian-consider-the-devotedness-of-muslims-and/8386#8386

Comment: @mike ..that is not what I am really looking for in my question. May be I have not made it very clear. To put it bluntly “Whether all other religion are man made”

Comment: Ok - I think that is a different question. And “Whether all other religion are man made” is actually clearer than your current title. Cheers.

Comment: Semi-related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9899/214

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer the main portion of the question from a purely Biblical perspective.  I anticipate that this question as well as this answer is going to generate a lot of debate, so I'm framing my answer as one from an in-arguably Christian perspective - one that's based on Scripture.

The presence of other religions is addressed in Romans 1.  (Quote below is KJV)

> 20 For the invisible things of him from the creation of the world are
>   clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even his
>   eternal power and Godhead; so that they are without excuse:
>
> 21 Because that, when they knew God, they glorified him not as God,
>   neither were thankful; but became vain in their imaginations, and
>   their foolish heart was darkened.
>
> 22 Professing themselves to be wise, they became fools,
>
> 23 And changed the glory of the uncorruptible God into an image made
>   like to corruptible man, and to birds, and fourfooted beasts, and
>   creeping things.

In short, man decided to reject God, and searched for other gods fashioned after their own imaginations.  The Biblical answer to your question is that yes, all other religions are man-made.

---

*And yes, I realize that there are plenty who would say Christianity is man-made as well, but that's not what the question is asking.  Answers on this site are supposed to represent a Christian perspective, which is what this is, and is what the question specifically asked for.  [Whether or not this perspective is ***true*** or not is off-topic for this site.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt)*

Comment: The summary speaks a lot. They decided to reject the true God and faultered by searching for other gods fashioned after their own imagination and remained outside God's plan of salvation.

Answer (score 3):

> How Christians are expected to accommodate or view the existence and
>   presence of other religions vis a vis Christianity?

In the old Testament God used the nation of Israel to exterminate the inhabitants of Canaan. Those people had a practice of killing their own children in the worship of Molech. God told Abraham that this punishment would come on Canaan later in time because the cup of their iniquity was not yet full.

We need to be careful when we read the Bible and make the distinction between what God does and what we are called to do. When Christians decide they need to act in the place of God, we get things like the crusades. We are not Israel and even if we were, we should still not usurp God.

Paul gives an insight to dealing with other religions. He tells people that even though the practice of eating meat sacrificed to idols has no significance, the practice should be avoided because it might harm a weaker brother.

Here is a good principle to follow;

Romans 12:18  If it be possible, as much as lieth in you, live peaceably with all men.

Sometimes God calls someone to be an evangelist. This person may preach (herald, proclaim, or declare) the gospel of Jesus. Sometimes Christians attempt this without the calling of God and end up in their own strength making the name of Jesus and offense.

Peter tells Christians who are about to undergo severe suffering to be ready to give a reason for the hope that is within them. I think we can see in this the principle that we are to be ready to respond to the opportunities God prepares. However, we can make a mess of things if we try to make things happen ourselves.

We know that no one can come to Jesus unless the Father draws him. We should avoid argument, pressure, challenge, or sales pitch. I have told those of other religions that I am a Christian, but not as good a one as I should be. I want those of other religions to know that I am available at anytime to explain more, but that they do not have to avoid me as someone who is looking for any opportunity to coerce them.

Comment: I think this post would benefit from mimicking the formatting that I did on your other post.

Answer (score 2):

**There are so many bible verses that declare Jesus to be the only true Lord and that all other religions worship in vain that are too numerous to count.** Here are three for example:

> 6 Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me. 7 If you had known me, you would have known my Father also. From now on you do know him and have seen him.” (John 14:6-7, ESV)
>
> 11 This Jesus is the stone that was rejected by you, the builders, which has become the cornerstone. 12 And there is salvation in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given among men by which we must be saved.” (ACTS 4:11-12, ESV)
>
> 5 I am the vine; you are the branches. Whoever abides in me and I in him, he it is that bears much fruit, for apart from me you can do nothing. 6 If anyone does not abide in me he is thrown away like a branch and withers; and the branches are gathered, thrown into the fire, and burned. (John 15:4-5, ESV)

Now how we are to view those without faith in Christ is how we are to view lost sinners who pretend to worship God. Those without Christ who pretend to worship God are out of necessity idolaters for they worship images in their own mind that blaspheme the grace of God in Christ. This is not to say there is not some ‘truth’ in all religion, it is only to say that the glory of the gospel is perverted so badly that the end result is the human religion that they use to replace it. God wrath is against all these false religions.

> 18 For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who by their unrighteousness suppress the truth. 19 For what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has shown it to them. 20 For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal power and divine nature, have been clearly perceived, ever since the creation of the world, in the things that have been made. So they are without excuse. 21 For although they knew God, they did not honor him as God or give thanks to him, but they became futile in their thinking, and their foolish hearts were darkened. 22 Claiming to be wise, they became fools, 23 and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images resembling mortal man and birds and animals and creeping things. (Romans 1:18-23, ESV)

At the time of Christ idols were physical and in some religions they still have them, but religions that hold ideals or beliefs about being saved by their good works, rather then faith in Christ alone, are no less idolatrous than mere idols made of stone. The idols are still based out of their foolish hearts resembling mortal man and not the only Son of God who died as an atoning sacrifice for our sins. Current Judaism of course suffers under the same curse for it still rejects its only hope, Jehovah in Jesus, the only Christ of God, the only true God.

Comment: Those are pertinent verses about exclusivness of need for faith in Christ for salvation.

Comment: @jayyeshu - the first theee are the rom 1 chapter is classical in describing religion outside of that exclusive path. In both repsects these are onky sample verses the Bible attributes the faithless to absolute corruption and consideres nothing morally good coming out of it. All other religions are of the 'flesh' and Paul said, for ex,  Romans 7:18
For I know that nothing good dwells in me, that is, in my flesh. The 'flesh' refering to human nature without new life in Christ is a contemptible word, this spans any religious expression under it, because it suppressed the divine laws in nature.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of other religions are mentioned in the bible, often combined with advice or examples on how to act.

Other religions are mentioned in the context of “the last days” or “end of days” in the OT in Micah 4:5 (from the new Jerusalem Bible):

“For all peoples go forward, each in the name of its god, while we go forward in the name of Yahweh our God for ever and ever.”

About which the Pulpit commentary writes: “All people will walk; rather, all nations walk. Everyone in the name of his god. "To walk" is generally used of moral and religious habits (e.g. 2 Chronicles 17:4; Psalm 89:31; Ezekiel 5:6, etc.); so here the meaning is that all other nations adhere to their false gods, and frame their life and conduct relying on the power and protection of these inanities, and, by implication, shall find their hope deceived. And we will walk in the name of the Lord our God.”

Other religions are also mentioned in the NT in Acts 17:21-24. 
In which St. Paul tried to find common grounds in the worship of those of other religions, in order to tell them about the “Lord of heaven and earth”.

And indirectly and directly mentioned in Romans 10 (as also quoted in an earlier answere verses 20:23), but in addition I would like to highlight the unmentioned verses 12-14

"12 it makes no distinction between Jew and Greek: the same Lord is the Lord of all, and his generosity is offered to all who appeal to him,
13 for all who call on the name of the Lord will be saved.
14 How then are they to call on him if they have not come to believe in him? And how can they believe in him if they have never heard of him? And how will they hear of him unless there is a preacher for them?"

So also here St. Paul sets an example to Christians, to respectfully try to tell followers of other religions about the Lord such that they can know his name and can be saved.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).